# How to pass data into Vue instance so that subsequent updates are reflected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, vuejs2

I'm trying to dynamically update a Vue JS prop after the view has been loaded and the custom has been initialised. I'm building a custom Vue plugin and am using props to pass options, one of which is a object which I need to dynamically update the value passed after the component has loaded, e.g:

```html
<div id="app">
  <script>
  var seedData = {
    percent: 50,
    name: 'Smith'
  }
  setInterval(() => {
    seedData = {
      percent: Math.random(),
      name: 'Smith'
    }
  }, 1000)
  </script>
  <offers :parent-data="seedData"></offers>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('offers', {
  template: '<h1>Parent Data: {{ parentData.percent }}</h1>',
  props: {
    parentData: {
      default: () => ({
        percent: 0,
        name: 'John'
      }),
      type: Object
    },
  }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

This will load the initial name/values from `offersData`, however, the new values on the `setInterval` doesn't get passed through.

I've tried adding a watcher inside of my custom Vue plugin that gets loaded through `<offers>` but this doesn't seem to work either:

```js
watch: {
  parentData: function (newVal) {
    this.parentData = newVal
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The following is my implementation:

Code Pen -> https://codepen.io/sts-ryan-holton/pen/VwYNzdZ

Comment: I really doubt this is the code you are using. All data referenced by template must be in the context of Vue instance (`this`). Paste the real code....

Comment: I just need to update the value of `offersData` after the page is loaded, and have these values passed into my plugin. The `<offers>` element is a Vue JS plugin, loaded into a normal website that isn't Vue

Comment: What you posted is not Vue plugin. [This](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) is Vue plugin. Post a real code or create reproducible example on codepen/jsfiddle if you want help. What you posted is not enough

Comment: Here's a Code Pen of what I need to do, be able to update a prop outside of Vue, I'm probably mistaken, I'm using a component as a plugin, see: https://codepen.io/sts-ryan-holton/pen/VwYNzdZ

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code

1. Everything inside `<div id="app">` is treated by the Vue as a template and compiled - see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el)

> If neither `render` function nor `template` option is present, the in-DOM HTML of the mounting DOM element will be extracted as the template. In this case, Runtime + Compiler build of Vue should be used.

Including `<script>` tag there is wrong. Just try to include `vue.js` (debug build) instead of `vue.min.js` (minified production build of Vue) and you will see bunch of errors (btw its always good idea to use debug build for development as it gives you lots of useful errors and warnings)

The fact that it "somehow works" in prod build (ie the initial values are shown on the page) doesn't mean it's supported...

2. So the inside of `<div id="app">` is template for Vue. As I said before in the comments, all data referenced by template must be in the context of Vue instance. You cannot pass some global variable into props. So moving `<script>` outside of `<div id="app">` won't help

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "seedData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initialising the property.

What you can do is to pass `seedData` object into root Vue instance like this:

```js
       var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            seedData: seedData
          } 
        });
```

Now the errors are gone but data changes is not reflected still. Reason for that is not Vue specific. Its simple JavaScript. Object are passed by reference in JS. Look at this code:

```js
var a = { name: 'John' }
var b = a
a = { name: 'Smith' }
// b is still pointing to "John" object
```

To workaround it, don't replace whole object. Just mutate it's properties (beware of [Vue reactivity caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats))

```js
      setInterval(function() {
          seedData.name = 'John';
          seedData.percent = Math.random();
      }, 1000)
```

Whole solution:

```js
Vue.component('offers', {
  template: '<h1>{{ parentData.name }}: {{ parentData.percent }}</h1>',
  props: {
    parentData: {
      default: () => ({
        percent: 0,
        name: 'John'
      }),
      type: Object
    },
  }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    seedData: seedData
  } 
});
```

```html
<script>
      var seedData = {
        percent: 60,
        name: 'Smith'
      }
      setInterval(function() {
          seedData.name = 'John';
          seedData.percent = Math.random();
      }, 1000)
    </script>
    <div id="app">      
      <offers :parent-data="seedData"></offers>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
```